# Why can't I access 'Advanced Settings' on an IIS website with only a net.tcp binding?

Tags: wcf, tcp, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

In our production environment (Windows Server 2008 R2) we have a handful of WCF web services hosted as individual IIS 7.5 websites. Each website has two bindings; an HTTP and a net.tcp. The HTTP bindings are never used to call the service, this is only being done via the net.tcp binding.

Now when I'm about to create a handful of new websites for additional web services, I thought it would be convenient to only add a net.tcp binding, since that's the only one we're actually going to use.

So now I have created a new empty website with only a net.tcp binding. In IIS Manager's leftside pane, in the 'Sites' listing, the website's globe icon has a red circle with a white cross on it. If I add an HTTP binding to it, the icon turns into a question mark instead, indicating it has multiple protocols. With only the net.tcp binding set up, I am unable to access the website's 'Advanced Settings' button from the rightside pane. But when it has a HTTP binding, the 'Advanced Settings' button is there. I need this in order to access the property "Enabled protocols" in Advanced Settings, where net.tcp needs to be added. Am I forced to have unused HTTP bindings simply because of this, or am I missing something?

Comment: The same faulty behavior still exists in the IIS Manager of Windows Server 2012 R2.